# PHP: Check if page is displayed inside iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

I would like to use PHP to check if the page is being loaded in an iframe. Preferably, but not required, I would like to have the parent's url when applicable. Thank you.

Comment: Javascript will be able to determine this

Comment: Once php finishes executing it sends the output to apache and apache makes it available to your browser so once it gets rendered by your browser php is no longer "active", assuming you have control over the page that is using your page as an iframe you can add a parameter to the url indicating this is "iframed", that would help you take any decisions you would need on your php script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Php cannot tell the context for which the request is made.  It doesn't know anything except what is passed to it and available as server variable.  You could add your own get parameter to the url to be used when putting your page in an iframe, but otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: I will have to use a parameter in conjunction with JS for visibility of content. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`JavaScript` is required for this; there is absolutely no way for PHP to know dependably.  In JavaScript you could use

```
window.top === window.self;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, In 2021 this is possible to check `URL` Embed on iframe or not with [`get_header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) PHP's function, I made this below function :

```
public function allowEmbed($url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/') {

        try {
            $headers = get_headers($url);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $headers = [];
        }

        $blackList = [
            'x-frame-options: sameorigin',
            'x-frame-options: allow-from',
            'x-frame-options: deny',
        ];

        $headers = array_map('strtolower', $headers);

        $check = array_intersect($blackList, $headers);

        if(!$check) {
            return ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Passed'];
        } else {
            return ['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Fail'];
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some possibility to detect iframe by PHP global variable $_SEVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. In this variable is a url of parent window.

Comment: It's not very reliable, even according to [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: PHP is a web server and is involved only in the dynamic building of html code and delivery over a network.  Details about ways the HTML is rendered in a browser are accessible via javascript.

Comment: This will not work the referrer will always be your site that is in the iframe.  I have tried this and the first page load worked fine but as soon as you click a link in the iframe the referer is now your site and not the site holding the iframe.

Comment: PHP is server side language. There is no way in PHP to detect iframe.